# Moving and renaming an uploaded file

Tags: php, html

Sorry if this is easy but I'm slightly new to programming so I'm having problems renaming a temporary uploaded file. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<input type="file" class="upload-img" name="logo" id="image" accept="image/*" />
```

PHP:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['logo'] ['tmp_name'], "images/".[logo])) {
    print '<p> Your image has been uploaded </p>';
} else {
    print '<p> There was an error with the image</p>';
}
```

Would anyone be able to tell me how to correctly rename the temporary uploaded image to 'logo'?

I currently get an error that says:

> Warning: fopen(images/logo.png): failed to open stream: No such file
>   or directory in /home/matos/public_html/pdftest/tfpdf.php on line 1443
>   FPDF error: Can't open image file: images/logo.png

Comment: what's wrong with your current code?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: I get an error: Warning: fopen(images/logo.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/matos/public_html/pdftest/tfpdf.php on line 1443
FPDF error: Can't open image file: images/logo.png

Comment: Just 'logo' with no file extension? `"images/".[logo]` isn't valid syntax  (unless you have a constant variable called `logo` but it would still not give you the desired effect). Instead of `"images/".[logo]` use `"images/logo"`

Comment: @Terminus the file extension should be PNG. Can I specify that in the code?

Comment: yes. you sould specify your file extension. @marcos

Comment: @JeesKDenny How do I specify the file extension? `"images/".["images/logo.png"]`?

Comment: @marcos yes definitely. Realize that the file extension doesn't actually affect the content of the file. Simply add the desired file extension to the destination string. `"images/logo.png"`

Comment: @marcos don't brackets around the string. That is shorthand syntax for creating an array. You may benefit from following a through a few more tutorials.

Comment: check the answer @marcos

Comment: @Terminus Thank you! Removing the brackets fixed it :)

Comment: @Terminus If you type your response the answers section I'll checkmark it.

Answer (score 0):

first you should know the type of the file. `$_FILES['logo']['type']` will give you the type. Check below code.

```
    $extension = explode("/", $_FILES['logo']['type']);
    $rename="logo.".$extension[1];

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'], "images/" . $rename)) {
       print '<p> Your image has been uploaded </p>';
    } else {
       print '<p> There was an error with the image</p>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the absolute path of images folder?

I assume that the form submit file to /pdftest/tfpdf.php

and /home/matos/public_html/pdftest/tfpdf.php is the script handle uploaded file. If the images folder's absolute path is /home/matos/public_html/images
your code should be

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['logo'] ['tmp_name'], "../images/logo.png")
```

Because the base path on your context is the folder of main script which I assume is /pdftest/tfpdf.php, it was /home/matos/public_html/pdftest/ on your local. When you save the uploaded file the real path will be

```
/home/matos/public_html/pdftest/../images/logo.png
shorted /home/matos/public_html/images/logo.png
```